# Indexing from a list of strings in C?

Tags: arrays, c, char, c-strings, function-definition

Obvious newbie question, I'm trying trying to write something that you put in an int and it gives you the month. Here is a function python version:

```
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
def get_month(mon):
    return months[mon]
```

In C, I have done this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *months[12] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};


int main()
{
char get_month(int m)
{
    return *months[m];
}
        
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    char    this_month = get_month(i);
    printf ("Month %d is %c\n", i, this_month);
}

return 0;
}
```

I get this output

```
Month 1 is J
Month 2 is F
Month 3 is M
Month 4 is A
Month 5 is M
Month 6 is J
Month 7 is J
Month 8 is A
Month 9 is S
Month 10 is O
Month 11 is N
Month 12 is D
```

I think I have to somehow account for  the length of the strings (or are they technically chars?) in *months[12] but I don't know how. If I change it to *months[12][3] I get

```
warning: returning ‘char *’ from a function with return type ‘char’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

Also, what if they were not all the same length (i.e. the months were written out fully)?

Comment: So you want to get the whole month instead?

Comment: Consider this: `get_month` returns a `char` but you want it to return a string, i.e. a pointer to an array of characters `char *`, the solution should then be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a function within another function is not a standard C feature.

You need to move the definition of the function `get_month` above main.

Elements of the array `monhts` have the type `char *`.

```
char *months[12] = { /*... */ };
```

So the function `get_month` that returns element of the array must have the same return type as the type of the array elements.

```
char * get_month(int m)
{
    return months[m];
}
```

So within the for loop in main you need to write

```
char   *this_month = get_month(i);
printf ("Month %d is %s\n", i, this_month);
```

As for this expression `*months[m]` then it yields the first character of the string pointed to by the pointer `months[m]` because you have an array pf pointers.

Answer (score 1):

1. The function:

```
char get_month(int m)  // this declares function which returns a single char
{
    return *months[m]; // months is array of pointers. months[m] gives pointer to string. *months[m] dereferences that pointer giving the first character of the month name.
}
```

it has to be:

```
char *get_month(int m)  // this declares function which returns pointer to the char array.
{
    return months[m]; // months is array of pointers. months[m] gives pointer to the char array containing the month name
}
```

2. Do not define functions inside other functions.

Move your function definition outside the `main` function.

3. Your variable has to type of pointer to char as strings in C are arrays of `char`s : `char *this_month = get_month(i);`
4. Use correct printf format:
   `printf ("Month %d is %s\n", i, this_month);`
5. Use correct `main` definition. If it does not take parameters it had to be `int main(void)`
6. Format your code properly

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *months[12] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

char *get_month(int m)
{
    return months[m];
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        char    *this_month = get_month(i);
        printf ("Month %d is %s\n", i, this_month);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your method the return type is char instead char* so you can only return a single character instead of a string.

```
char get_month(int m)
{
    return *months[m];
}
```

The next problem is that you dereference the value which is looked up from the array
so instead a pointer to the string you get the value at the start address of that string, which is the first letter.

Try this instead:

```
char* get_month(int m)
{
    return months[m];
}
```

Comment: Also the `printf` format specifier. `%c` -> `%s`.

Comment: And the `char this_month =`.